# What is the simplest way to see the file name of the websites content?

Tags: php

I'm working on the PHP code of someone else and can't find the source file of a certain content. I'm looking for a solution which gives me an easy access to the file name of anything displayed on the website. I did some researches but don't know how to work with that and was hoping to find something like Firebug for the CSS of the website.

[I found this](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/dirlist/#.UdRFUvky06o)

The PHP is this:

```
<?PHP
function getFileList($dir)
{
// array to hold return value
$retval = array();

// add trailing slash if missing
if(substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir .= "/";

// open pointer to directory and read list of files
$d = @dir($dir) or die("getFileList: Failed opening directory $dir for reading");
while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
  // skip hidden files
  if($entry[0] == ".") continue;
  if(is_dir("$dir$entry")) {
    $retval[] = array(
      "name" => "$dir$entry/",
      "type" => filetype("$dir$entry"),
      "size" => 0,
      "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry")
    );
  } elseif(is_readable("$dir$entry")) {
    $retval[] = array(
      "name" => "$dir$entry",
      "type" => mime_content_type("$dir$entry"),
      "size" => filesize("$dir$entry"),
      "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry")
    );
  }
}
$d->close();

return $retval;
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to parse the HTML source and look for tags like img src , a href etc.

Comment: can you not search the file system?

Comment: If the site is using a mod_rewrite or other rewrite rules, you may find that the URL location of a page doesn't have much bearing on the server side application files.

Comment: @sgroves I can and I did - for te last two days! But I wasn't able to find it. I checked the files over and over again but somehow I can't see it...

Comment: besides my answer: if you got the default LAMP stack (linux apache mysql php) and no cms/framework in place, you can check for rewrites/url routing on the server side by enabling the rewrite log and then querrying an url - the server should then log which file it is accessing (doc for apache here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html )

Comment: did you do an actual grep or just search manually? `grep` or `find` should be able to locate anything you're looking for

Comment: @sgroves I was trying to find it by checking each file, line by line. But there so many of them and it's obviously that I missed something. I'm not sure that I understand your question what is the difference between manually search and [grep] / [find]

Comment: @dethtron5000 I appreciate your feedback and yes, I've got the LAMP stack and no cms-framework! I checked the link and to be honest I doubt that my skills are good enough to work with that. But I will try...

Comment: stefan assuming you have access to the command line, you can search files with the linux `grep` command

Comment: @sgroves & dethtron5000 Thanks again for your interest. I just tried it again with Google "view-source" and was finally able to find what I was looking for. Since the content was in connection with a link, It showed it as "a href:"xyz" " and xyz was the file name I was looking for. I actually checked this before - but somehow missed it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Not possible.

Long answer:

Which file is generating the content you're looking for depends on many factors. For a simple system it could be 1:1 filename to url mapping like /index.php => DOCUMENT_ROOT/index.php, and for a more complex system a single line of output might be generated by thousands of files, each printing a single character. Even if your urls are something like xyz.css it might still be generated by a .php file, or even by a file ending with .xyz or without filename extension at all.

Most popular CMS systems already use some kind of url routing / apache ( / whatever webserver ) rewrites, and without knowing anything about the system you're talking about (you aren't really providing much info) it's totally impossible to give a correct answer.

If you got more info on the system you're looking at (programming language is supposedly php - is there some framework used? php extensions? some php cms? maybe it's mixed php and some other language? which webserver? in case of apache/lighttpd/... are there rewrites/url routing in place? ...) you might get a better answer.