# Get .html filename of a website with Firebug

Tags: html, firebug

How do I find the filename of an website I am inspecting with Firebug?  As example when I look on http://example.org/ I can view inspect the Element, I see the whole html structure but I didn`t find the filename. I am searching for index.html or something in that way. Maybe this is an analog question, but I am not sure, because he/she is working with php. [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452752/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-see-the-file-name-of-the-websites-content)

I know there are some solutions with Dreamweaver or other tools but I am searching for an easy way to figure that out with Firebug or an free Browser Add-On. I Hope you have a solution for that.

Comment: Why do you want a filename of a website

Comment: in my case i have to do some changes on the webside. and no i don`t want to change CentOs it is just an example. the link is only an example

Comment: I would have thought the simplest way would be to FTP to the server & check the filename?? If you are making changes to the site you must have some sort of access.

Comment: that would be a great idea if i had only 1 or 2 sides...  but unfortunately i have a little bid more of them.

Comment: You **must** have access to the server to change the files. Having a big number of websites you need to modify, doesn't change this.

Comment: i have access to the server and i have all the html local. My question is about the possibility to identify the filename of an website i am inspecting with firebug.  do you know a way to do that ?

Comment: I have adjusted my answer to explain how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you entered is the one that usually returns the main HTML contents. Though on most pages nowadays the HTML is altered using JavaScript. Also, pages are very often dynamically generated on the server.

So, in most cases there is no static .html file.

For what it's worth, you can see all network requests and their responses within [Firebug's *Net* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel).

Note that the URL path doesn't necessarily reflect a file path on the server's file system. It is depending on the server configuration, where a specific URL maps to in the file system. The simplest example is the index file that is automatically called when a domain is accessed. In the case of http://example.org the server automatically loads a file index.html in the file system, for example.
So, in order to get the file name on the file system, you need to either check the server configuration or the related access logs.

Comment: Ok for example.org it is an index.html file. But how you found that out ? I tried it with the net panel, which holds a lot of information’s but I haven`t found an entry with index.html. 
And yes i got you right and i understand that i have to check server logs & configuration. Anyway thanks for your infos

Comment: That was a wild guess, as servers are normally configured to serve `index.html` as index file.

Comment: understand... thank you the answer is enough for me..  all the best an keep on rockin :-)